# Angular 2 - traceur not found

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm getting a strange error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/app/traceur 404 (Not Found)
```

My app builds, but when I try to go on it, it doesn't load and this error comes up in console. For some reason, when I remove the `directives` section of this component then the error goes away:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContextService } from './../../services/ContextService';
import { Herd } from './../../classes/shared/herd';
import { Animal } from './../../classes/shared/animal';
import { CalendarWidget } from './../../classes/calendar';
import { Schedule } from 'primeng/components/schedule/schedule.d.ts';
import { Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

@Component({
    selector: 'dash',
    templateUrl: '/templates/Dash/dash.html',
    providers: [CalendarWidget],
    directives: [Schedule] // when I remove this line then it works
})

export class DashComponent implements OnInit
{
    public animals: Animal[];
    public constructor(public router: Router, public context: ContextService, public calendar: CalendarWidget) {}

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.animals = this.context.herd.GetAnimals();
        this.calendar.events = this.context.user.getEvents(1); 
    }

    onSelect(animal: Animal) {
        this.router.navigate( ['AnimalDetail', { id: animal.ID }] );
    }
}
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on? A few people seem to have encountered this error in the past but none of the fixes worked for me.